# Problem with pstricks captioning, packages etc

Tags: pstricks

I'm new by `pstricks` and trying to make my plots with it, but I am facing some problems.

1. I cannot place my plots wherever I want to in the page as I did for `pict2e`. How can I fix the plots where I want them to be?
2. I don't know which packages are used for each plot. For example, which package should I use when I'm plotting axes and using `\psaxes` and such examples? Where can I find a good reference for that?
3. How can I make a caption for my plots? The way I used to make captions in `pict2e` is not that much useful here. For instance the code which is below :
   ‎

   ```
   \documentclass{book}‎
   \usepackage{pstricks}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

   \begin{document}‎

   ‎\begin{figure}‎
   \begin{center}‎‎
   ‎\psline[linewidth=‎1‎pt , ‎linecolor=red‎‎]{<-‎‎}(-1,1)‎‎
   \psset{linecolor=green}‎‎‎‎
   ‎\psline[linewidth=3pt]{>->}(2,-3)‎
   ‎‎\psline[linewidth=‎1‎pt , ‎linecolor=yellow‎‎]{-‎‎>}(‎0‎,1)‎‎
   ‎\psline[‎linecolor=orange , ‎linewidth=‎1‎pt]{-‎‎>}(1,‎0‎)‎‎
   ‎‎‎‎‎\psline‎‎‎[‎‎‎‎‎linewidth=‎2‎pt ,‎ ‎linecolor‎=magenta ‎‎]‎‎‎‎{-‎‎>}(1,‎4‎‎‎‎)‎‎
   ‎‎\psline[linecolor=‎magenta‎,linestyle=dotted](‎‎2,‎3‎)‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
   {\psset{linecolor=green,linestyle=dotted}\psline(‎2‎,4)}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
   ‎‎\caption{‎first arrows‎‎} ‎‎
   \end{center}‎‎
   ‎\end{figure}‎‎

   ‎\end{document}‎
   ```

[image: the pdf file of the above code]

Comment: Please remove all that unnecessary white space from your picture.

Comment: I would if I knew how can I do it

Comment: There are lots of tools for that. If you are on Windows there is for example MS Paint.

Comment: oh , I see  , I thought that you mean by LATEX , I'll do that for my next posts .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is tons of documentation on your system! Run `texdoc pst-plot` and you'll get the one from package `pst-plot`, or visit http://PSTricks.tug.org

You do not need the `figure` environment if you want to place the image at a particular place in your doc:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-3)(2,4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=red]{<-}(-1,1)
\psset{linecolor=green}
\psline[linewidth=3pt]{>->}(2,-3)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=yellow]{->}(0,1)
\psline[linecolor=orange,linewidth=1pt]{->}(1,0)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=magenta]{->}(1,4)
\psline[linecolor=magenta,linestyle=dotted](2,3)
\psset{linecolor=green,linestyle=dotted}
\psline(2,4)
\end{pspicture}
\captionof{figure}{first arrows}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The tutorials from TUG India at [PSTricks site](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=doc/docs) mentioned above are an excellent way to start learning.